# Records Insert and receive the error of ORA-00001: unique constraint (table1_PK) violated

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have a stored procedure which is inserting the records filtered out from a table to another.

But when I run the stored procedure, I get an error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (table1_PK) violated

I checked the constraints, that is a `Primary_Key` constraint. And in my insert, I did not insert any value for the primary key and it should be generated and auto-incremented.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer this question by myself.
We finally find out that the reason was a couple of days ago we made a data refresh in the table from prod but forgot to sync the sequence. :( sign......